# Make timer only execute code on the first tick (Visual Basic)

Tags: xml, vb.net, variables, timer, intervals

I am trying to create a reminder system that would remind the user 2hrs, 1hr, 10min before the time set on the reminder, as well as on that time. To do this, I created timers for each certain element in an xml file. The thing is, I can't figure out a way to set the timers' interval correctly so that they can only tick once, nor can I adress them later and stop them because their variables are created inside the `For Each` loop.

Here is what I tried, which syncronizes the first tick like I wanted them to, but then they keep going and creating more notifications outside of the interval I want

```
For Each lembrete In odoc.Element("root").Element("Lembretes").Elements("Lembrete")
            Dim data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(lembrete.Element("Data").Value)
            Dim data As New DateTime(data1.Year, data1.Month, data1.Day, lembrete.Element("Hora").Value, lembrete.Element("Minuto").Value, 0)
            Dim t1, t2, t3, t4 As New Timer()
            
            t1.Interval = ((data - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds - 7200) * 1000
            t1.Enabled = True
            t1.Start()
            
            t2.Interval = ((data - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds - 3600) * 1000
            t2.Enabled = True
            t2.Start()
            
            t3.Interval = ((data - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds - 600) * 1000
            t3.Enabled = True
            t3.Start()
            
            t4.Interval = (data - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds * 1000
            t4.Enabled = True
            t4.Start()
            
            AddHandler t1.Tick, AddressOf t1Tick
            AddHandler t2.Tick, AddressOf t2Tick
            AddHandler t3.Tick, AddressOf t3Tick
            AddHandler t4.Tick, AddressOf t4Tick
```

What do I need to change to make it happen like I want it to?

Comment: In the tick handler event, the sender object will be the actual timer, cast that to a timer, then you have access to it's properties to disable it

Answer (score 0):

Put the statement "Dim t1, t2, ..." outside of the Sub/Function so that the timers can be accessed by other procedures.

Add this to **Sub t1Tick**:

```
    t1.Stop()
```